# Proving that $7n^{2}\log_{6}n + 12n +7$ is Big O of $3n^{3} - 4n^{2} + 12$

Tags: solution-verification, asymptotics, computer-science

Been banging my head against this problem for an hour now. The best I've been able to come up with is
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksPUs.png), but I feel like I'm still missing something. Am I on the right track? How should I approach this question?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Answer (score 0):

You only need concern yourself with the dominant terms.  For large $n$, $$7n^{2}\log_{6}n + 12n +7\leq 8n^3\leq 3(3n^{3} - 4n^{2} + 12)$$

Answer (score 0):

When $n$ is sufficiently large, we have $2n^3\leq 3n^3-4n^2+12\leq 4n^3$, and $6n^2\log_6n\leq 7n^2\log_6n+12n+7\leq 8n^2\log_6n$. So we just need to verify that $n^2\log_6n$ is Big O of $n^3$. Given that $\log n$ is Big O of $n$, this is true.